# Codigo jquery que cambia de texto al dar click en "ver más"

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

Tengo un código jQuery que sirve para mostrar y ocultar respuestas. Lo que quiero lograr es que en vez de mostrar el texto "ver respuesta" u "ocultar respuesta", muestre un icono, ejemplo un icono fa (`fa fa-plus`). ¿Cómo lo hago posible?

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#alternar-respuesta-ej5').toggle( 

        // Primer click
        function(e){ 
            $('#respuesta-ej5').slideDown();
            $(this).text('Ocultar respuesta');
            e.preventDefault();
        }, // Separamos las dos funciones con una coma

        // Segundo click
        function(e){ 
            $('#respuesta-ej5').slideUp();
            $(this).text('Ver respuesta');
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    );

});
```

Comment: Sería ideal si pudieras añadir un ejemplo del código HTML así como de lo que hayas intentado. De ese modo podríamos verlo funcionando directamente en la pregunta. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un pequeño codigo espero te sirva:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $('#alternar-respuesta-ej5').click((e) => {

    let clase= $(e.target).attr("class");
    
    if(clase === "mostrar"){
      let btn = "<i class='fas fa-minus'></i>";
      $(e.target).html("ocultar respuesta "+btn);
      $(e.target).addClass("ocultar").removeClass("mostrar");
    }else if(clase === "ocultar"){
      let btn = "<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>";
      $(e.target).html("ver respuesta "+btn);
      $(e.target).addClass("mostrar").removeClass("ocultar");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button class="mostrar" id="alternar-respuesta-ej5">ver respuesta <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
```